# How do I read specific data from a file using a Scanner object?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to store doubles into variables to be used for later methods, but every time I try to have my program look for a double it results in an error. How can I make my scanner object look for specific data (Such as doubles or ints) from a file?

```
import java.io.*;

public class YEHE31301 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File Master = new File("C:\\Users\\Nikko\\Desktop\\Master.txt");
        File Transaction = new File("C:\\Users\\Nikko\\Desktop\\Transaction.txt");
        Scanner MasterInput = new Scanner(Master);
        Scanner TransInput = new Scanner(Transaction);
        double x = Invoice(TransInput);

    }

    public static double Invoice(Scanner TransInput) throws IOException {
        double OverallBalance = 0;
        char Check;
        while(TransInput.hasNext() == true) {
            Check = TransInput.next().charAt(0);
            if (Check == 'O') {
                OverallBalance = OverallBalance - TransInput.nextDouble();
                System.out.println(OverallBalance);
            }
            if (Check == 'P') {
                OverallBalance = OverallBalance + TransInput.nextDouble();
                System.out.println(OverallBalance);
            }
        }



        return OverallBalance;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is potentially OK, but it will depend on the data that is in the files.  This looks like it would have the format of `one char` `space` `double` `one char` `space` `double` - it this right?

Comment: if you could post your file format it would be great!